# Update value column B if value in Column A matches a value in a list of values

Tags: mysql

In my 'domains' Table - Column A is 'name'. Column B is the domain name's 'owner'.

All the domains currently have their owners field set to the value 'NON'.

I need to loop through and update some of the domains to have the owner 'CJS'.

My query would be something like this I guess....

Update 'domains' set 'domains.owner' to 'CJS' if 'domains.name' *matches 'one these names'*.

Is their a way I can create a list (array?) of names against which I can check 'Column A' against?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` query. To test if a column is in a list of values, use `IN (list of values)`.

```
UPDATE domains
SET owner = 'CJS'
WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...)
```